# How do I handle improper length Base64 strings with c#

Tags: c#, encoding, base64

I know that a Base64 encoded file needs to have a length that is a multiple of 4. And to correct for that I can use the code below.

```
        int mod4 = s.Length % 4;
        if (mod4 > 0)
        {
            s += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
        }
```

This will add as many "=" as it takes to make it a length that is a multiple of 4. But I'm stuck with a situation where "=" signs may be present when they shouldn't be. I suppose I could remove any padding "=" 's and then add them back in if needed, but that seems silly. Is there a better way to handle Base64 Encoding that are messed up?

Comment: _"I'm stuck with a situation where "=" signs may be present when they shouldn't be"_ -- like, where someone went and added a bunch of `'='` characters to the string? Why would they do that? Why do you have to handle "messed up" encodings at all? Why can't you just insist that the source of these encodings give you valid ones? Alternatively, since the `'='` is actually not strictly required (you can infer the number of used octets in the last group without it), why not just decode the base64 without it? What have you tried, and why didn't that attempt work? Please provide a good [mcve].

Comment: The files are received "as is", and I Have no control over it. Insisting that an unknown entity properly formats their encoding is impossible in this instance. As far as what I've tried the code above to add them back after I removed them with s.TrimEnd('='); What I was looking for was a method that I haven't found (maybe because it doesn't exist) that can do that task for me. This is my first experience with Base64 so that's why I was looking for help.

Comment: _"Insisting that an unknown entity properly formats their encoding is impossible in this instance"_ -- that isn't generally the case. For example, if you were to try to post an image in your question, but the image file were invalid, SO wouldn't make any attempt to figure out what's wrong with the file. It would just reject it. In any case, without a clear problem statement, I don't see how you can expect good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you're looking for

```
s.TrimEnd('=');
```

Comment: I know, short answers are always voted down- but you can't make simple things even more simple and this is exactly what he needed to solve this.